# Upon sticking navbar to top of page, it goes from the middle to the very left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm currently working on a project and have the correct code for sticking the menu bar to the top once it has been scrolled passed. However, when the menu bar is not 100% of the page, it crunches to the left. Anyone have a clue how to put it right back to where it was?

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="menucontainer">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="History.aspx">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="Gallery.aspx">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services.aspx">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="stickyalias"></div>
```

jQuery CODE:

```
    $(function () {
        // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
        var stickyHeaderTop = $('.menucontainer').offset().top;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
                $('.menucontainer').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '0px' });
                $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                $('.menucontainer').css({ position: 'static', top: '0px' });
                $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    });
```

Some CSS code:

```
.menucontainer {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    clear: both;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: .9;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1100px;
    }
```

If it helps anyone at all, the page can be visited at [mor.actiongymok.com](http://mor.actiongymok.com/) to see the live version of it running.

Comment: Can we please see some your css?

Comment: My advice? Do it in purely css and don't rely on javascript for page layout.

Comment: @MatthewRath can you please show me an example of how to do it that way then?

Comment: Just use a regular horizontal menu bar and use `position:fixed` with a large z-index (to ensure it's always on top) animations can be css based also.

Comment: I'd suggest finding a framwork to support you. If you're fine with SASS bourbon / neat would probably be best (see [refills](http://refills.bourbon.io/) for examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your menu has a fixed width. When your menu sticks to the top, change the width of the class **.menucontainer** to 100%.

If you want that your menu remains from the same size, add the following CSS to your .menucontainer

```
  .menucontainer{
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   }
```

Comment: With the added code to the css element, this did the trick perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behaviour of a fixed element... If you haven't specified a `left` value it will default to `left:0;`. So to center it, give it:

```
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -550px; // half the width of your header
```

You will have to adjust this as necessary across breakpoints but that is why your nav is jumping over like that.

Comment: This worked correctly, but once the scroll came back up it messed that up. Especially with the dynamic layout of the page

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    // Check the initial Poistion of the Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('.menucontainer').offset().top;
    var menuContainerWidth =$('.menucontainer').outerWidth();

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop) {
            $('.menucontainer').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '0px',left:'50%',marginLeft:menuContainerWidth/2 + 'px'});
            $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $('.menucontainer').css({ position: 'static', top: '0px',left:'auto',marginLeft:'0px' });
            $('#stickyalias').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I like the way you're going here, but the jquery syntax does not like the margin-left css property.

Comment: Plus it did not work properly when I tried it that way.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using bootstrap3. It should come built into Visual Studio. It makes it so much easier using their pre built css.

Comment: Due to the fact that I needed a pretty custom navbar, I needed it done without bootstrap, but thanks!